# Why does the number of variables in my node seem to matter when I make a doubly linked list in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I was making a doubly-linked list in C and before it had three variables as its data (two ints and a bool after I threw in typedef int bool) and the two pointers next and prev.  I inserted in the back with a function that roughly said

```
void insert(list *l, int x, int y, bool z)
{
    node *n = makeNode(x, y, z);
    if(isEmpty(*l))
        l->head = l->tail = NULL;
    else
    {
        l->tail->next = n;
        n->prev = l->tail;
        l->tail = n;
    }
}
```

And my makeNode function said something like:

```
node *makeNode(int x, int y, bool z)
{
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(n));
    n -> x = x;
    n -> y = y;
    n -> z = z;
    n -> next = NULL;
    n -> prev = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

So then I print it out with something that looked like:

```
void printList(list l)
{
    node *i;
    for(i = list.head; i != NULL; i = i -> next)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", i -> x, i -> y, i -> z);
    printf("\n");
}
```

That one worked perfectly, but then I had

```
void reversePrintList(list l)
{
    node *i;
    for(i = list.tail; i != NULL; i = i -> prev)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", i -> x, i -> y, i -> z);
    printf("\n");
}
```

And that one segfaulted.  After playing around with the code, for some odd reason, while the "next" pointers remained intact every time, the "prev" pointers did not point to the nodes I originally had them pointing to, and apparently they weren't pointing at NULL either.

Furthermore, earlier I was trying to implement it as a circular doubly-linked list and for some reason still the next pointers worked just fine but the prev pointers once again were pointing somewhere strange.

But what's really weird about this is that when the nodes only contained one int, everything worked perfectly on both the linear and circular doubly-linked list.  And when I do a few syntactic changes to translate the code to C++, it works perfectly with the bigger node.  I looked all over and there was no code I wrote that was supposed to alter the prev pointers outside of the insert function.  So what is going on to mess up the prev pointers and only the prev pointers when I used a bigger node in C?

Thanks!

Nerd With a Vengeance

P.S. Here are my structs

```
typedef struct node{
    int x;
    int y;
    bool z;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;

typedef struct list{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} list;
```

Comment: I do note that `makeNode` doesn't return `n`...  Also, you're not using a `node*` to iterate over?  How can you *guarantee* that an int will have the sufficient bytes for each node?

Comment: Oh my bad.  I didn't have my code in front of me when I wrote those.  Hang on let me edit.  But I was iterating with a node* and makeNode did return n.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: wouldn't an empty list stay empty for ever and your malloc-ed node lost in the heap?

Comment: Your `insert` function is broken to the max, but I'm guessing this is you just writing code from memory and not doing copy'n'paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node *n = malloc(sizeof(n));
```

This doesn't make any sense. You want to allocate enough bytes to hold a node, not a pointer to a node. Try:

```
node *n = malloc(sizeof node);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for spotting that malloc mistake!!  The code works now!

Comment: An alternative form: `node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);`. This has the advantage that if it's an assignment statement rather than an initializer (`n = malloc(sizeof *n);`), the size expression can't get out of sync with the pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

What is this????

```
int i;
for(i = list.tail; i != NULL; i = i -> prev)
  printf("%d %d %d\n", i -> x, i -> y, i -> z);  /* WTF??? */
```

I would expect something more like:

```
struct mystruct {
  int value;
  struct mystruct *next;
  struct  mystruct *prev;
};
...

  struct mystruct *s;
  ...
  while (s != NULL) {
      printf("value=%d next=%x prev=%x\n", s->value, s->next, s->prev);
      ...
```

PS:
Could you post code for the definitions of "list" and "node"?  They might look promising...

Comment: O that? I saw something like that in the K&R Book where the iterations used a lot of flashy shortcuts so I figured that was supposed to be the way to iterate through your list in style. I'm just learning C right now so I'm not sure how the pros write their code so I just went by the book. And yeah I was just printing the values of the list as I went, so the pointers weren't in the print statement. So is this a style I should steer clear of?

Comment: @AndyHaskell I think paul's referring to the fact `i` is declared as an `int` instead of a `node*`.

Comment: Oshi- I forgot I used to sign my posts as Nerd With A Vengeance until I logged back in and got notified about your comment so have an upvote for that lolol

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a small thing in the else part of your insert function.
After the line l->tail=n,
I think  you should have 
 l->tail->next = NULL 
This is for assigning the last node's next to NULL. It seems missing from your code.